# Send product details to checkout page if not logged in first

Tags: php

My `index.php` has some products which a user can buy, after clicking buy button they are redirected to checkout page. If the user is not logged in, the checkout page redirects them to the login page. After logging in again it takes them back to the checkout page but during this whole process, the form data sent to checkout page from `index.php` which is set to send data to checkout through form gets lost.

How do I retrieve data if user is not logged in initially? There is no problem if a user is already logged in and clicks buy button. Put simply, index-to-checkout `$_POST` can get data but, index to checkout to login then back to checkout can not. How do I do it?

All my carts are saved in the database, I don't want to fetch same date again in checkout page and sending every detail as a parameter in URL seems clumsy. Also, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: As noted by JasonB, you probably should use a session or cookies, but cookies require the user to allow their use on their machine, so they are less desirable than a session.

Comment: When you save the carts in the database, what is the problem in loading them on the checkout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)?

The buy button sends data to the checkout page, the checkout page sees that the user is not logged in so it stores the posted form data and redirects to the login url. The login url has a redirect parameter in the url so a user knows they'll be headed back to the checkout after logging in but no clunky purchase data. The checkout page could check in the session data for saved parameters if the necessary data isn't in $_POST.

Comment: is there any other way than to use session.

Comment: There are other ways, but since you mentioned no jquery I went straight to server side and sessions seems easiest to work with there for this solution. You could use cookies, you could have all of the checkout data stored as hidden fields on the login form that you fill in with php to pass from form to form (yucky!), you could have database storage or a tempfile that you write on the server that stores the data with some type of indentifier like ip...

Comment: @makehappen2017 Why do you not want to use sessions?

Comment: i am using session for password recovery to send data different page, unfortunately if a user doesn't complete the password reset, there is no way to clear session. Any one can access reset page directly form URL, if it has been initiated once. I don't want to encounter similar problem again.